# python different behavior of hello world on different computers

Tags: python

If only I could delete this question, I would.

<s>My girlfriend wanted me to show her programming basics.</s>

We both downloaded the exact same programs

- notepad++ for editing
- python 3.4.3 from this link https://www.python.org/downloads/

the program

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
print (var1 + var2)
```

gave in my computer

```
3
```

and in hers

```
12
```

obviously, mine refers to var1,2 as ints, and hers as strings.

What could have caused this?
How to know what's going to happen in real code on different machines?

I run windows 8.1

She runs some windows 7

Comment: I hate to say it but it's almost certainly pebcak imho..  It happens to the best of us. (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=PEBCAK).   Is there a possibility that this is down to unicode problems?  Try entering in ms notepad.

Comment: I won't believe it, until I see the screenshot of her code.

Answer (score 3):

Your code must be,

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
print (var1 + var2)
```

Addition takes place here.

and her code must be,

```
var1 = '1'
var2 = '2'
print (var1 + var2)
```

String concatenation takes place here.

Comment: Python doesn't behave like that. There **must** be an error on your side.